# Common Logging Output

Tags: logging

I want to turn on logging in StandardXAPoolDataSource (org.enhydra.jdbc.pool).
It seems uses JCL logging.
I am using tomcat 6.0.

The questions is how to output the log to the file ?

Thanks.